# For complex request is rest better than graphQl

Tags: rest, graphql, apollo-client

I have a complexe request to send to the server . In sumary i am creating a feed system

So in my request i use 2 tables.
First i start with the login user id and i pull all the other users he is following from a FOLLOW table .

So now I have the logged in user plus an array of other user he is following .

Second step is i use a FEED table the complexity is i would like to pull all the action from this table that are eitheir performed by the main user or the following users.

I am using Graphql for all my other request ... however for  a complxe request like this one . I am thinking that REST is more suited

I would like to know your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this complexity?

You can use one graphql query - `user{followers{feeds{action..` and `user{feeds{action...` - both `action` arrays will be available in Apollo.

You can always combine results from these 2 arrays into one on **client side** from [normalized] Apollo cache [for some component needs]. You have both sets separated as they are separated in reality and universal for future needs/other app/client/admin.

If you really want/need it combined **serverside** just add user to his followers in resolver for query like `user{userAndFollowers{feeds/action...` - it can be done beside main/separated schema, just by adding additional 'branch'.

It always depends on details ... but REST better? in witch version/convention/'standard'? good joke ;) - no offence, tons of pro/cons/comparisions everywhere ... try/read/choose suitable to requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such term as `better`. It all depends on what you need, what your architecture is and after all, what you know to use better.
GraphQL is great for such complex request because you can return exactly what you need and nothing more. So if you're asking if GraphQL can handle it, for sure it can!